# How can resolve this AJAX error 500 in prod mode?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I've a problem and I don't understand why. 
In my Symfony project, I've 2 AJAX functions and both worked before but not anymore and I haven't change nothing.

Here's an example :

This is my function in my Controller

```
/**
* @Route("/{name}/add/add-console", name="add-console-ajax")
*/
public function addConsoleAjax(string $name) : JsonResponse {

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$userID = $this->getUser()->getId();

$console = $em->getRepository(Console::class)->findOneBy(['name' => $name]);

$user = $em->getRepository(User::class)->find($userID);

        if ($user->getConsoles()->contains($console)) {
            $user->removeConsole($console);
            $em->flush();
        } else {
            $user->addConsole($console);
            $em->persist($console);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return new JsonResponse([
            'console' => $console
        ]);
}
```

And this is my function in my JS :

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: `/videogames-collection/public/${consoleName}/add/add-console`,
  data: JSON.stringify(formData),
  dataType: "json",
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  cache: false,
  success: function () {
    console.log('Success!' + formData);
    location.reload();
  },
  error: function () {
     console.log("Error in Ajax function");
  }
})
```

When I work in local I need to delete this part **'/videogames-collection/public'** in the path and everything works. But now that doesn't work anymore online and I don't know why. I always have an error 500.

Do you have an idea ?

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: Did it and it was a permission issue. I've change the permission on 777 for the folder var/cache/prod and that's work! 
Apparently we need to change the permission more than once with this folder because I've already did it before...

But thanks! Problem solved!